# Nonlinear Conjugate gradient for vector valued multi variable functions?

Tags: vector-analysis, gradient-descent

So far what I have found in online and in Numerical recipes book describe algorithm for scalar value multi variable function. Can anyone point me to the algorithm for nonlinear conjugate gradient for vector valued ($x_1(u,v)$,$x_1(u,v)$, $x_1(u,v)$....$x_n(u,v)$) function? My cost function is the discrete harmonic function that is widely used in computer graphics: 
$E = \sum_i \sum_{j,(i,j)\in E} ||v_i - v_j||^2$, each of $v_i$ & $v_j$ has two directions $(u,v)$; $u_i=u_i(u,v), v_i=v_i(u,v)$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $E$ is scalar valued.  You'd normally apply the nonlinear CG method to $E$.

Comment: @Brian Yes, I understand this. But I am confused about the variables. All the algorithms that I see consider each variable as a scalar variable. But for my case, each of the variable is a vector. So the function is : $R^{n x 2}$->$R$. Can you suggest something how to handle this or any link that you know?

Comment: Typically if you have a matrix of variables you reshape it into a vector (in this case of length $2n$) of variables for optimization.

Comment: Great, thank you so much, got something to try.